# NuGet Package cpprestsdk 2.6.0 in VS2017 get Error LNK2019 unresolved symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, cpprest-sdk

I've try to make a simple C++ REST Client on a Win7 computer with cpprestsdk and VS2017. So I've used NuGet package Manager to install cpprestsdk in Version 2.6.0, because I must use source code on a linux machine with only a 2.6 version so far.

I've no glue to resolve linker errors like:

> LNK2019   Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall web::uri::uri(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (__imp_??0uri@web@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)" in Funktion ""public: class Concurrency::task __thiscall CRESTClient::AmArsch(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?AmArsch@CRESTClient@@QAE?AV?$task@X@Concurrency@@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)".   GPRSServer  d:\Users\lmahle.admd\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\GPRSServer\GPRSServer\crest_client.obj

.. any many others.

I try to add the include and lib path to the "VC++ Directories" without luck. I know what the error means, but have no idea what to do.

I thought installing with NuGet inside the project do all the creepy stuff with linking and adding directories, but no chance.

Unfortunately I have no idea, which directory I must use (or should I), because there are 4 for v120 and 2 for v140, Think it's must be ...foo.winapp.msvbla... or ...foo.winxp.msvbla...

Dealing with huge XML-target files is not my goal, think there must be a simple solution (missing a checkbox anywhere?) outside and hope some professionals can get a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same here sigh. but only when running on diff vs version across the build servers. local works fine. - same issue with linking in dll's - works fine if using vc++. Not on c++ compilers (even though I don't see any other dependencies)